# Can Members of Congress be Charged with Incitement (and etc.)

Tags: united-states, constitutional-law, us-constitution, official-immunity, incitement

Following the recent Capitol Riot I started to wonder about incitement. I ended up wondering about members of Congress, who are protected against arrest and questioning for what they say when Congress is in session ([Constitution Article I, Section 6, Clause 1](https://constitution.congress.gov/browse/essay/artI-S6-C1-1-3/ALDE_00001048/)). If during a session of Congress, a Representative or Senator urged their supporters to invade the White House, but refused to comment outside of Congress, could they be charged with incitement? Furthermore, if yes (or no), to what extent could this be pushed? Could a member of Congress ask their supporters to assassinate members of the other party? Could the 14th amendment be applied to bar them from office for participating somewhat in an insurrection?

Comment: [My question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/47628/what-prevents-the-doj-from-charging-democrats-in-congress-under-u-s-code-2383)  along these lines was not well-received.  But it does have a [good answer with references](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/47631/11306) covering many aspects of this question.

Answer (score 2):

### Not in court

The [speech or debate clause](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_or_Debate_Clause) protects statements made in the chamber from civil or criminal proceedings absolutely. However, the House or Senate (as applicable) can take action including expelling the Congressperson.

Comment: Unless it was a breach of the peace or treason or felony.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite.  no. not even then.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite That's the list of exceptions to "they can't be arrested on their way to or from or during session".  Though the clause is, I think, not quite as absolute as Dale describes, though it's fairly close in practice.  The clause only covers official duties, or "legislative speech" and its surrogates (in this way it covers staff members, memos, etc.). Speech which has no relevance to their duties is not covered.  But that's a very broad umbrella.  My expectation is that advocating for insurrection on the floor is protected, but actively coordinating an ongoing insurrection is not.

Comment: The protection provided has been ruled to be absolute whenever it applies, that much is true, but there are uncovered actions that it doesn't protect.  The Pentagon Papers incident protected Senator Gravel's reading and entering of the papers into the Senate records, but not the attempt to have them published by a non-profit.  SCOTUS specifically limited the clause to official duties of a Congressman, extending that to cover aides, but not more; his aides were not immunized from grand jury testimony concerning third party crimes, etc.

Comment: @grovkin - have you read the provision?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite yes, the exception applies to the attendance clause of the sentence. it does not apply to the speech clause (that appears after the semicolon) because the speech clause has its own verb.  A qualifier attacked to one verb does not qualify the other verb after the semicolon.  This is basic grammar.

Comment: I see that you are correct. In fact it is so separate that grammar would say it is unconnected with the prohibition on being arrested. I guess you just can't question them.